# Save value as other table value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a HTML form that saves all entered values to a sql database. One of the options is a dropdown menu populated by the database. I need a way to save the populated option as it's id number instead of the readable name the user is presented. The ID number is another column in the entry

Currently using this to populate the dropdown:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM venue";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='venuename'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: Don't forget to include `<form></form>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the `id` column and put it in the `value` attribute.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM venue";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='venuename'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```